# Why can't type Id a = a be partially applied to data D f = D (f ())?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I also tried the following with the LiberalTypeSynonyms extension as suggested in [When (if ever) can type synonyms be partially applied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29462675/when-if-ever-can-type-synonyms-be-partially-applied), and have added an explicit kind signiture to `f` in `Id`'s definition. I still got the same error. I don't know if there are other extensions that might help.

```
ghci> type Id a = a
ghci> type Const a b = a
ghci> data D f = D (f ())
ghci> (((() :: Id ()) :: ()) :: Const () a)
()
ghci> D () :: D Id

<interactive>:10:9:
    Type synonym ‘Id’ should have 1 argument, but has been given none
    In an expression type signature: D Id
    In the expression: D () :: D Id
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = D () :: D Id
```

This really confuses me. `f` in `D` is `* -> *` and `Id` is `* -> *`. What more is there to this?

Comment: Partially applied type synonyms are essentially equivalent to type-level lambdas, which make the type checking algorithm much more complex. GHC does not allow them. Use `newtype`s or `data`s wrappers instead, and wrap/unwrap your values with a constructor as needed. Otherwise, switch to Agda or Coq :-P

Comment: By the way, the liberal-type-synonyms rule does not give you much more flexibility, only a little. If after the expansion of all the type-synonyms, we still have partially applied ones, a type error is triggered. If you had `type D f = f ()` instead, the extension would allow for your code. But `D f` would be the same type as `f ()`.

Comment: @chi that clarifies the extension for me.  Unfortunately, in my particular problem, I can't have D be a type synonym, but I might manage with having Id and Const be newtypes. Your "it's too complex for GHC" comment qualifies as an answer. I might accept it if you post it as so, but maybe I should wait a little more, in case someone else wants to post too.

Comment: [I also fell for something like this once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881351/why-cant-you-totally-apply-a-type-synonym-that-has-arguments-using-an-other-t).

Comment: @Bakuriu looks like I posted a duplicate. I couldn't find your question. Sorry, guys.

Comment: @Bakuriu Both of the examples in your question compile with `LiberalTypeSynonyms`; whereas the example in this question does not compile even with `LiberalTypeSynonyms`. So I agree with you that it is related, but not with jlmg that it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haskell's type system does not support partially applied (also known as *unsaturated*) type synonyms or families. `data` types and `newtypes` do support partial application, though.

```
newtype D f = D (f ())
newtype Id a = Id a

d :: D Id
d = D (Id ())
```

`newtype`s are erased during compilation, so the only cost you're paying is a syntactic one.

Comment: Except when it's not :(. Ed Kmett wants to add `liftCoercion :: Maybe (Coercion a b -> Coercion (f a) (f b))` to the `Functor` class, and similar methods to `Contravariant`, `Bifunctor` and `Profunctor`, to make coercions more generally applicable and thus more newtypes free.